# Why is z-index not working even on a positioned element?

Tags: css

I am learning to create pure CSS3 ribbons

I have

```
.dialog h1 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.dialog h1:before, .dialog h1:after {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -10;
}
```

but my CSS triangles (`.dialog h1:before/after`) are still shown in front of the `h1`. why is that?

http://jsfiddle.net/w9Hqd/2/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see
http://jsfiddle.net/w9Hqd/3/

Comment: So you removed the `.dialog h1 { z-index: 10 } `. But why does it cause the problem? Shouldn't it be rendered in front of something (the triangles) with the lower `z-index`?

Comment: @jiewmeng I'm not quite sure, I need to do some experimentation before  providing a correct explanation.